# JFrame freezing when I call a class using JButton

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Im not really an expert in programming and Im just starting to learn. Here is my problem.
I tried to call this [class](https://github.com/manishiitj/screenshare/blob/master/src/DisplayServer.java) to start the server using a JButton but after the button was pressed the application freezes.

Here is my mouseClicked event

```
private void startbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
      new DisplayServer(80);
}
```

Comment: Check that you are not stuck in an infinite loop. Your code should have better indentation. I read it half way and gave up.

Comment: Most likely you end up running a loop on the event thread, blocking all GUI events and drawing (you need a separate thread). It's also a very bad idea to have `new DisplayServer(80);` result in more things happening than creating the object. You should have a separate `start()` method that you call, instead of starting execution directly from the constructor. I recommend all the possible basic tutorials before you start to work with Swing.

Comment: @user3437460, I believe the GITHUB is not OP code, look the commit date ;)

Comment: @user3437460 Sorry for that. Its someone else code so Im really not familiar on that code.

Comment: Are you even sure this code is working? Using an external/unknown source might be your problem. From what I see, this will simply open a socket. Did you checked if it was opened ? Debug this to have more information. But for now, this is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you block the Event Dispatcher Thread. Try to run it in a new Thread.

```
private void startbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                          
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
          new DisplayServer(80);
      }
  }).start();                      
}
```

For more info read the article about [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: You can see in the Github that the `DisplayServer` wait clients in the current thread `client = ss.accept();` at line 27. So this is correct. If find that a bad design, The server should manage the Thread itself (my preferences)

Comment: @JarrelCostiniano please read the mentioned above article, to understand why you should implement your listener this way